# Display data on another sheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to program a summary sheet in Excel. The sheet is supposed to pick data from other sheets. I use Excel 2010

Bascially I have some data on a page called Nige. Column C provides name of locations, column K contains % growth. I want to refer to that page from a new sheet to identify the Percentages on column K that are less than 75 and display all the corresponding location names (from column C) and their percentages (from column K).

I also want to display those that are within range 65% to 75%.

This is the code that I am using. It runs but displays an empty cell so I am sure I am not doing someting right. The data runs from C7 to K230.

```
IF(ISERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(NIGE!B$7:K$230),SMALL(IF((INDIRECT(NIGE!K$7:K$230)<=75),ROW(INDIRECT(NIGE!K$7:K$230"))),ROW()))),"")
```

[Link to picture of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hcA6.png)

Comment: Instead of this elaborate question of 15 different Columns with 15 different descriptions and items, it would be much more helpful, if you provided a simple example of 1) screenshot with your current data and 2) of your expected result instead.

Comment: To add to that, would definitely recommend to read this StackOverflow meta-post called "[How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: HI. I am a new comer and i am not allowed to embed pictures in my posts yet. so i have included a link that you can check out.

Answer (score 0):

We need to mark or identify the rows to be displayed.  In **L7** enter:

```
=IF(AND(K7>64,K7<76),1,"")
```

and in **L8**  enter:

```
=IF(AND(K8>64,K8<76),1+MAX(L7:L$7),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

*(you can change the helper formula if the percentages are fractional)*

Then in another sheet in **A1** enter:

```
=INDEX(Nige!C:C,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Nige!$L:$L,0))
```

and in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(Nige!K:K,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Nige!$L:$L,0))
```

and copy these downwards:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. is there anyway to do this in ascending order based on the number in column K in the first picture you shared? so in essence, the least number gets to be the first on the list in the dashboard page